# New Google accounts don't show up in Calendar app

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I added a Google account to my phone and turned on calendar sync for it.

When I went to the Google Calendar app, that new account is missing from the list and also missing in the "Manage calendars" settings.

How do I get my calendar to show up for the new account?

Comment: Have you tried adding the account from the Google Calendar app?

Comment: If I try that under "Manage calendars" by clicking the `+` sign, it says `This account already exists on your device`. After I did that, it suddenly showed up in the list. However, no events are syncing that are any newer than 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to the Google Accounts in Setup

- Setup
- Accounts and Backup
- Manage Accounts
- Add Account

It should pick it after that.

Comment: I already added the account that way. It still doesn't show up.